# Flash downloaded code into STM32F4 MCU; how do I remove the downloaded code?

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I'm new embedded electronics and am learning via online tutorials.  I built and downloaded a code (with the uVision IDE) which made the blue and orange LEDs flash.  I want these LEDs to stop flashing, and I want the MCU to go back to the state it was at before I downloaded the code.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, You want to erase your micro-controller.

- For STM32 you have different options, If you are using ST-LINK, I think the best solution would be "STM32 ST-LINK UTILITY" which you can download [here](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/flasher-stm32.html)
- Or you can use built-in Bootloader which can be enabled by BOOT pins and so on.
- And you can also use your development environments such as IAR, KEIL or something like that.

Additionally, Never worry about the downloaded program, you can always erase your application even you enabled the read-out protection option.

Comment: I do have the KEIL IDE, but it won't let me flash erase (option is disabled).  And how would I use the built-in bootloader to flash erase?

Comment: Ah, I see. It being flash memory means that clearing it really isn't necessary

Comment: That last part isn't entirely correct. There are some protection modes which will permanently prevent any future access to the microcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

How to return:

1. Write FLASH mass erase function
2. Copy mass flash erase function to the RAM.
3. Jump to it
4. Do the software reset